# Internet freezes

Tags: wifi, software-installation, drivers, nvidia, gnome-terminal

I can surf the web just fine, but as soon as there are videos on a site, the mouse freezes and I have to shut down to move forward.  Do I need to install nvidia 340, 390, and/or nvidia Driver 418-server?  Could it be a weak wireless connection?  I am new here and just learning my way around.  I am also very reluctant to put codes in in the terminal because I see other options for downloading. I'm not understanding the terms such as: Executable file for Linux, Flatpack Package Format, and Personal Package Archive for Unbuntu in relation to downloading software like Inkscape, for example. I'm using elementary os on 27 inch iMac late 2012.  Thank you for helping me get over a couple of these basic but necessary, hurdles to better understanding.

Comment: In your browser, disable hardware acceleration. You'll need to then restart the browser, so make sure it's completely restarted and then try to play an online video. This won't *definitely* fix it, but odds are pretty good and it's one of the first steps I use to troubleshoot these sorts of errors.

Comment: I was using Epiphany and couldn't find an option to change what you suggested, so I switched to Firefox, and easily found the preference you were referring to!  Problem solved-Thank you KGIII

Comment: You can try [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10311/how-can-i-turn-off-hardware-acceleration-in-epiphany). I don't have access to my virtual machine install right at the moment. If I get a chance tomorrow, I'll type it up as a complete answer.